# Regression analysis- transformation of predictor variables

Tags: analysis, statistics, regression

I have been given a table of values for 3 variables: the predictor variables X1 and X2 and the response variable Y. I am told that the response values were generated based on some non-linear function using the predictors X1 and X2. Eg, f = EXP(X1) + x1*X2 + (error term) and that I am to estimate this equation using Multiple Linear Regression.

The problem is, the data that have been generated don't show any immediately obvious transformations that I could apply. [Matrix plot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC38S.jpg)

So, while I understand the need to transform the data, how am I supposed to know which transformations would be appropriate? Is there any systematic approach to problems like this? Or am I just supposed to keep guessing transformations like ln(1/X1^2), exp(X1*X2) etc until I hit on one that looks correct?

Thanks in advance.